# How do I create a manual point-to-point wicked network configuration?

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, opensuse

I am tasked with working on an OpenSUSE 42.3 server (without desktop environment) that I'm looking to connect to a Windows10 laptop (configured as 192.168.1.2) using ethernet (in order to run other non-CLI configuration GUIs remotely).

I originally tested and successfully configured a link with Network Manager (NM) on a Leap 15.2 laptop, which I could produce with the command:

`nmcli con add con-name wired2Windows ifname eth1 type ethernet ip4 192.168.1.1 802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate yes ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 connection.zone home`

Feeling pretty pleased with myself, and feeling well-armed, I entered the 'data-cave', where the fearsome servers lurk (and the lights switch off automatically after 5 minutes - yes, I took a head-torch!), to find that the OS42.3 machine was configured with *wicked* not NM; henceforth my resolve crumbled, and after some fruitless messing with Yast2, I retreated to lick my wounds.

Next, I 'found' an old server running Opensuse 12.1; this predates wicked, but, again, I've managed to create a reliable command:

`sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.1 pointopoint 192.168.1.2`

Now, before I re-enter the data-cave, I want to prepare myself with a reliable equivalent command that works with *wicked*. It would be great if this were simply:

`sudo wicked ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.1 pointopoint 192.168.1.2`

but reference to the [*wicked* man page](https://www.mankier.com/8/wicked) suggests that life is not that straightforward.

To recreate my simple point-to-point link:

1. What files do I need to edit in /etc/wicked/ ?

ifcfg-eth1 currently looks like this (transcribed from a photo - presumably modified as a result of my attempt to configure using ncurses Yast2):

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
DHCLIENT_SET_DEFAULT_ROUTE='yes'
ETHTOOLS_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR=192.168.1.1/24
MTU=''
NAME='I210 Gigabit Ethernet Connection'
NETMASK=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
```

which seems to have a lot less info than [this example](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-network-interface-configuration-file-etc-sysconfig-network-scripts-ifcfg-eth/):

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth0
UUID=...
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=0e:a5:1a:b6:fc:86
IPADDR0=172.31.24.10
PREFIX0=23
GATEWAY0=172.31.24.1
DNS1=192.168.154.3
DNS2=10.216.106.3
DOMAIN=example.com
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

2. What do I need to edit in /etc/sysconfig/network
3. Do I need to specify a DNS (even though I have no external network connection)?
4. Would the command then be:

`sudo wicked ifup eth1`

As you may have gathered, I only have very restricted access to the server room, and negotiating further visits is neither straightforward nor convenient, so a reliable solution, or selection of viable possible solutions would be exceptionally welcome. Thanks.

**Edit**: I've got this so far in ifcfg-eth1:

```
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.1/24
LINK_REQUIRED=no
REMOTE_IPADDR=192.168.1.2
```

but note that REMOTE_IPADDR does not appear to be translated to wicked's XML config:

```
<interface origin="compat:suse:/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth1">
  <name>eth1</name>
  <control>
    <mode>manual</mode>
    <link-detection>
      <require-link>false</require-link>
    </link-detection>
  </control>
  <firewall/>
  <link/>
  <ipv4>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <arp-verify>true</arp-verify>
  </ipv4>
  <ipv4:static>
    <address>
      <local>192.168.1.1/24</local>
    </address>
  </ipv4:static>
  <ipv6>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <privacy>prefer-public</privacy>
    <accept-redirects>false</accept-redirects>
  </ipv6>
</interface>
```

Comment: it appears that I can create a temporary solution using: 
  `ip address add dev eth1 192.168.1.1[/24 | peer 192.168.1.2/24]`

I'd still like to know how to make this a permanent (on boot) configuration, using wicked.